# Passing a Unknown struct (at runtime) as a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to create a generic template function which will accept a unknown structure, as parameter, during runtime. By Unknown struct, I mean that I will not have knowledge of struct member variable names and their corresponding data types and values. The function should then deduce the type of all the structure members, one by one, and their corresponding values. I am not concerned with the structure members count, as I can have a structure member function returning the numbers (hardcoded). What I am unable to understand is how to get the incoming structure member types, and their corresponding values, dynamically, at run time. Here is my code till now:

```
struct test1 //Any struct of this type will be passed as a parameter to the template function, with more or less the same data types
{
    int n1;
    double d1;
    std::string s1;
    double d2;
    std::string s2;

    int sCount() { return 5; } //Hardcoded
};

    template <class T>
    std::string structToString(const T& st)     //Pass unknown struct as input
    {
        //I am not able to understand how to get all the structure members, one by one, and their types and values at run time

    }

    int main()
    {
        test1 obj = { 0 };
        obj.n1 = 10;
        obj.d1 = 12.23;
        obj.s1 = "XYZ1";
        obj.d2 = 13.65;
        obj.s2 = "ABC1";

        structToString<test1>(obj);

    return 0;
    }
```

I can probably use something like `typeid(T).name()` for each of the struct members to get their types, but how to iterate all the (unknown) members, and also get their values.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *What I am unable to understand is how to get the incoming structure member types, and their corresponding values, dynamically, at run time.* AFAIK, you can't do that.

Comment: You might be interested by [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), but requires C++14.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. But it seems that the programmer has some knowledge/expectations about the struct members, but in my case it should be totally generic...

Comment: What you want is called "reflection". C++ does not provide a way to do it, but there are some reflection proposals in the committee process, so a future version might.

Comment: *"T must be constexpr aggregate initializable and must not contain references nor bitfields"* which is the case for `test1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You can for specific implementations of your template function.

What you have so far is a good start, but you need one more thing. You need to define your `structToString()` function for the specific struct you want to be able to convert to a string. Like so:

```
template <>
std::string structToString(const test1& st)     //Pass KNOWN struct as input
{
    // Now you have access to struct test1's member data
}
```

Now, any time you call `structToString()` with a `test1` object, it will call this new method, but any other structs that don't define a `structToSting()` method will call your generic one. (Which you could then have return "[Unknown]", or similar)

Comment: Incidentally, C++ will automagically choose the right specialized function to call so you can just call `structToString(obj);` instead of spelling the whole thing out with `structToString<test1>(obj);`

Comment: You might prefer overload instead of specialization.

Comment: Specialization would allow for a default function. Overload would fail at compile time if a specific method wasn't made available.

Comment: With a template specialization, if a `structToSting()` method does not exist for your defined struct, then the original function (as defined in the question) would be called, allowing you to run your code without defining a `structToString()` method for each type you use.

With an overloaded function, then a `structToString()` method must be defined for each and every struct you use in your code, otherwise your code won't compile.

So you have a trade off between getting your code up and running quickly vs. ensuring that everything you need is defined.

Comment: I didn't imply to remove the template version, just add overload (`std::string structToString(const test1& st)`) (which would be a better match) instead of specialization. so in both cases, if not provided, the generic method is called.